# Do Weeping Angels Displace Other Weeping Angels?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

Is there anything to show what happens when Weeping Angels touch?  Do they displace each other?  It would seem to me they could use this to provide each other with unlimited life.  Displace an angel a few hundred years and you get a lot of life (since they are long life creatures), then when that angel comes back to the present, it could displace the first one.

Do they displace each other?  Or become aware of each others' existence and position so neither one can move from then on?

Can they touch and survive?  What effect does touching one angel have on another?

Answer (score 5):

**No, they cannot displace each other through time to feed on temporal energies.**

Otherwise they would have done that instead of fading away to almost nothing when they were discovered by the Doctor and River Song in the episode: S05xE04 - A Time of Angels. Those Angels had been trapped on the planet for some time and were starving to death.

They have a host of powers some of which include:

- In their natural native state, they appear as statues carved in stone. This stone is impervious to harm when they are immobile. They can enter a state of suspended animation and are capable of surviving for centuries in this state.
- Unless killed by a being who understands their true nature, using phenomenally powerful technology, they are relatively immortal.
- They feed on the temporal energy of subject while sending it back in time to a period equal to the lifespan of the subject.
- They are also able to exist in a variety of adverse electromagnetic radiations which would be dangerous to most life forms become "dinner to an Angel. The longer they bathe in radiation, the stronger they will grow," said the Doctor during A Time of Angels.

Comment: They don't send people back in time to a period equal to the lifespan of the subject -- if this were the case, Martha, the Doctor, and Billy Shipton would not have all ended up in the same year. The doctor mentions they must have been touched by the same angel to end up in the same place, but whether that's biological for the angel or a choice the angel makes is not clear

Comment: It would be awesome if they could, and then it would be like _Highlander_. Kind of.

Comment: Who is to say angels don't just consider 'cannibalism' wrong? They might be able to displace each-other, but there are also a lot of humans who would rather starve to death than to eat another human being, especially if they knew they were immortal anyway and would one day wake up again.

Comment: TBH, I'm willing to bet you put more thought into this than the writers did!